# What's the opposite of "envious"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

What's the opposite of *envious*? For instance, I felt X when I got accepted into MIT and my sister did not. Or, when you feel bad for being lucky, when someone else is not.

By googling, I found *unenvious* but I'm afraid the word might not exist at all, because the Cambridge dictionary has no entry for it.

I feel bad in the first example because my sister and I wanted to study together at the same university. I'm quite happy that I got accepted, but sad at the same time because my sister did not.

Comment: In the first example, are you feeling high-n-mighty about it, or bad about it, as in the second example?

Comment: @JasperLoy Say you and a friend both want to be astronauts; your friend is more qualified, but you get in. You feel bad now, because he/she *should* be where you are. As an example.

Comment: @Mahnax: Improved, hope it's clear now.

Comment: Perhaps you feel smug?

Comment: Are you're looking for something similar to survivor's guilt? except that in this case you it wasn't a bad situation that you survived but a good situation that came to pass for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say that you feel sorry for your sister, or that you *pity* her. You could also feel *reluctance* towards going to the university because she will not be going. Even if unenvious was a word, I don't believe it means the same thing as what you're looking for; it simply means *not envious*.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm after. Maybe my examples don't meet the case. As another example, my fiance recommended me to download a movie, when the download finished, I felt ___ because it had taken her three days to download it and it was quick for me. She lives in another country (say Zambia).

Comment: @JasperLoy: Well, I can't take a photo of the feeling. that was all I could think of to explain it.

Comment: @JasperLoy I'll pitch in a few bucks for that, if it means clearer questions.

Comment: @Gigili - Based on the movie download example are you looking for the word "guilty"? From *guilt* - a feeling of responsibility or remorse for some offense, crime, wrong, etc., whether real or imagined.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the word you are describing doesn't appear to be the opposite of *envious* - "For instance, I felt X when I got accepted into MIT and my sister did not. Or, when you feel bad for being lucky, when someone else is not."

The opposite of envious would be your sister being happy for you that you were accepted at MIT. Words like *gracious* and *supportive* come to mind.

Your example sounds more like *ambivalent* - " simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action" ( http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent ).

Answer (score 3):

The simple antonym would be *content*, or *satisfied*...something along those lines. You could also extend it further by being *smug* or *self-satisfied*. Both of these concepts do not include direct reference to another person's relative fortune, though.

What you're describing, though, is at least two other concepts that have nothing to do with envy per se: misplaced guilt ("Why did I get in and she didn't?" and disappointment ("I'm going to miss not going to school with her.").

Edit: I meant no insult in my answer, but it sounds like I have offended you. Let me offer one more suggestion anyway: *mixed feelings*,relief/joy at getting in, along with sadness / disappointment about your sister.

Comment: As you said, what you explained here is really simple and not the antonym I look for. I asked if there is a single word for that, not a book. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I agree with @JeffSahol, it sounds like "guilt" would be the right word/feeling. You feel guilty for getting in and your sister didn't and you feel guilty you managed to download the movie much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *envious* has an opposite, but, in the circumstances you describe, you might feel you were *undeserving*.

Comment: I think, in the example, she (who got accepted) may well feel that she fully deserves it.